# Possible connection: Milan Malpensa airport to Milano Centrale

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, milan, mxp

I am travelling to Italy next week. My arriving airport is Milan Malpensa, which is quite far from the city centre.

What is the best way to go to city centre or central station?

I guess there are some shuttle trains, but how much do they cost?

Comment: Get [Uber](https://www.uber.com/), maybe?

Comment: That is a good choice as well.

Comment: Uber in Italy is *very* different that what you might be used to in the USA. There are many laws, and protests going on against these laws, currently being discussed as to whether to authorise uber cars to behave like taxis. A lot of legalese blabla which means that recently the Italian legislative system ruled a bunch of limitations regarding the service. The situation is changing dynamically on a weekly basis. Beware.

Comment: In general, Uber is never a good choice, USA or not. A) the very business model of the company is based on dismantling the rule of law. What would happen if every company could pick at will which laws they ignore and sell this in a nice package? B) they are working on reestablishing indentured servitude. Educate yourself then vote with your wallet and stay away.

Comment: @chx: I've seen you make those shrill claims repatedly, always without any sources or substantiation. **Can** you substantiate them? "Dismantling the rule of law" and "reestablishing indentured servitude" is something one generally needs to conduct an armed overthrow of a government to do -- the notion that a private business would be able to (let alone interested in) do those things is an extraordinary claim that demands extraordinary evidence. You have provided zero evidence; that is far from extraordinary.

Comment: I have almost always substantiated them, but if you need them again, here's a few: [2014 article](http://valleywag.gawker.com/uber-and-its-shady-partners-are-pushing-drivers-into-su-1649936785) [2016 article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2016-05-31/inside-uber-s-auto-lease-machine-where-almost-anyone-can-get-a-car) [2016 tweet](https://twitter.com/shashashasha/status/688734478181732352). As for dismantling the rule of law, they willfully ignore taxi regulations everywhere, that's their existence. As I said, what would happen if every company could pick a regulation to ignore?

Comment: Ps. http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74855/is-there-a-practical-way-to-change-the-phone-number-in-uber-app-when-arriving-at#comment194808_74855 contains these exact same links.

Comment: Pps.: they now decided to ignore self driving car legislation and put cyclists in deadly danger. https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2016/dec/19/uber-self-driving-cars-bike-lanes-safety-san-francisco

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Public Transport to/from Milano Malpensa

Two options come to mind.

#### 1. Malpensa Shuttle

The [Malpensa Shuttle](http://www.malpensashuttle.it/e-index2.php) takes you from Malpensa to [Milano Centrale](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Centrale+F.s./@45.4873397,9.2058816,16z/data=!3m1!5s0x4786c6dac59b464b:0xb22ccd0f8b781684!4m7!1m4!3m3!1s0x4786c6c54ff75843:0x2226b1141a97cf2a!2sMilano+Centrale+Railway+Station!3b1!3m1!1s0x4786c6c543258035:0xe45af66393986777), the main train station in Milan, in (claimed) 45 minutes. Single fare is 10`EUR`. The shuttle also stops at Rho-Fiera which is a Metro A stop that is not exactly in the city centre but is well served by public transport.

[Here](http://www.malpensashuttle.it/web2011/e-tariffe.php) is the up-to-date webpage with the Malpensa Shuttle ticket fares.

#### 2. Malpensa Express

The [Malpensa Express](http://www.malpensaexpress.it/en/) train also takes you from Malpensa to [Milano Centrale](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Centrale+F.s./@45.4873397,9.2058816,16z/data=!3m1!5s0x4786c6dac59b464b:0xb22ccd0f8b781684!4m7!1m4!3m3!1s0x4786c6c54ff75843:0x2226b1141a97cf2a!2sMilano+Centrale+Railway+Station!3b1!3m1!1s0x4786c6c543258035:0xe45af66393986777), the main train station in Milan, in 46 or 52 minutes depending on the number of stops served by the train. Single fare is 12`EUR`.  Trains depart every 24 minutes or so, alternating between not-so-direct trains and slightly-less-direct trains.

Moreover, since you ask about the city centre, the Malpensa Express also operates a route to [Milano Cadorna](https://www.google.fr/maps/place/Milano+Cadorna/@45.4692037,9.1739796,16z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x4786c1502726bdad:0x813fefc2e5e07786), which is a regional train, as well as Metro A and B, station right-smack in the centre of Milan. The journey time are 29 minutes for the direct train and 36 minutes for the train with intermediate stops. The price reamains 12`EUR`. Trains depart every 30 minutes or so, alternating between direct trains and not-so-direct trains.

[Here](http://www.malpensaexpress.it/en/malpensa-express/tickets/ticket-fares.aspx) is the up-to-date webpage with the Malpensa Express ticket fares.

### Get the Train

In my opinion the Express train is better because its arrival/departure times are not road traffic-dependant. You can safely assume that the shuttle can suffer delays during peak traffic hours in Milan (mornings and evenings).

Comment: I think I will travel by train. It is good choice for me. Is there any price difference with buying instant ticket and buying ticket earlier?

Comment: If I recall correctly there is no price difference. See [here](http://www.malpensaexpress.it/en/malpensa-express/tickets/where-to-buy-tickets.aspx) for ticket-buying options.

Comment: Thank you, but what about the whole Italy? Is it also true for regional trains?

Comment: [Come to the chat.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591/you-are-here) ;)

Comment: I'll second the train, but do check the schedules in advance! As I recall, it sometimes runs less often than you'd like, and Malpensa is not the nicest airport to wait in.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to catch a suburban train to Milano Centrale, which you can book [here](http://www.trenord.it/EN/)

PRO TIP: do **not** buy a ticket from Malpensa to Milano Centrale, which costs €13, but two separate tickets Malpensa-Busto Arsizio Nord (Busto Arsizio Nord being the first or second stop) and Busto Arsizio Nord-Milano Centrale, which cost €4 each=€8 in total.

Bottom line: you can definitely catch the train for less than €10.