# Transfer between Milan airports: Malpensa - Linate

Tags: airports, airport-transfer, milan, mxp, lin

Recently I've booked a flight with a layover in Milan. I've realized that the transfer is between different Milan airports: Malpensa (MXP) and Linate (LIN).

I've already found a shuttle bus to transfer: http://www.malpensashuttle.it/

1. Maybe someone can suggest any cheaper and faster way to get from one airport to another (3 adults, 2 kids)?
2. If I have some 9-10 hours between the flights maybe it's worth making my route through the city center?

Comment: What do you mean by `better`?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity, I mean in terms of price and speed.

Comment: (1) seems like a reasonable and probably common question to me

Comment: @Calchas It is reasonable *now* that the parameter score has been reduced. `best` is a qualitative subjective measure rendering the question unanswerable as per SE philosophy. `cheapest` and `fastest` on the other hand are objective quantitative measures which make the question fit for the site and thus answerable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In my opinion the shuttle bus is the cheaper option because the total price will be 52 euro (13 euro each adult, 6.50 euro each kid between 2-12 years).

For comparison, taxi ride price from Malpensa to Linate is 85 euro.

In addition 5 people will have a lot of bags, so the shuttle bus is the best option in order to carry them easily.

Comment: I see two issues with the taxi: unless you are lucky enough to find a Fiat Multipla taxi waiting outside the airport, you'll need to prebook a taxi capable of carrying 5 passengers. Moreover there are extra fees for more than 3/4 passengers (depending on the consortium rules). My point being that the taxi ride for 5 passengers plus luggage will probably cost more than the flat 85EUR rate and might be more complex to organise from abroad.

Comment: of course, I indicated the taxi price just to confirm that the shuttle bus is a cheaper solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Take The Shuttle, Man

Since you mention 5 people plus luggage my advice would be to aim directly for your destination airport (Linate), regardless of how long your layover might be. I'm thinking that from a practical standpoint the last thing you want to do is roam around a foreign city attempting to kill time whilst hauling around luggage and trying to keep 2 yougsters under control. :) To this purpose, the most direct transport - i.e. the Malpensa Shuttle you mentioned - is in my opinion your `best` option in terms of practicality. In terms of speed you can imagine the Malpensa Shuttle being only slightly slower than a taxi, since coaches must abide to slower speed limits, assuming that the driver does in fact follow them. [Your journey time is of 1h10 to 1h30 depending on the bus you take.](http://www.malpensashuttle.it/carico/documenti/linate-malpensa%282%29.pdf) The [price calculation by Guido](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/48665/22140) is correct at the time of writing. For more information [here is a link to the official webpage with the ticket prices](http://www.malpensashuttle.it/web2011/e-tariffe.php).

### A Ride into the City

For completeness sake note that you can get from Malpensa to Linate by going through Milan by public transport. [First things first you'll have to reach the city](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/44187/possible-connection-milan-malpensa-airport-to-milano-centrale?rq=1), be it with the Shuttle (`10 x 3 + 5 x 2 = 40 EUR`) or with the Malpensa Express train (`30 + 12 = 42 EUR`) (30 is the family ticket for 2 adults + 2 children up to 18 years old).

Once you are in Milano, be it at Centrale or Cadorna train stations, you'll need to purchase an urban single fare ticket (`1.5 x 5 = 7.5 EUR` at the time of writing) and find a way to get to a bust stop served by line 73 or X73 (the express service to the airport). Personally I suggest the San Babila stop since it's central and served by the metro. Hence from Centrale you'll take Line 3 (the yellow one) towards San Donato, get off at `Duomo` and change for Line 1 (the red one) towards Sesto 1o Maggio FS, and get off at `San Babila`. From Cadorna you'll just need to get on Line 1 (the red one) towards Sesto 1o Maggio FS, and get off at `San Babila`. Once you are there look for the metro exit on Corso Europa, since that's where the 73 or X73 buses depart from.

Total cost for this journey into the centre of Milan would be:

- Malpensa Shuttle to Centrale: `40 + 7.5 = 47.5 EUR`
- Malpensa Express to Cadorna: `42 + 7.5 = 49.5 EUR`

Total time for this journey would be:

- Malpensa Shuttle to Centrale: `50 + 20 + 41 = 111 minutes`
- Malpensa Express to Cadorna: `29/36 + 20 + 41 = 90/97 minutes` depending on if you take the direct train to Cadorna or not

Yes either journey seems to be cheaper than taking the Shuttle all the way. At the cost of sounding repetitive I will say that in my opinion it's not worth saving a couple euros opting for a journey that is either as long or slightly longer but *ever* more tedious.

**Get the shuttle, man.**

#### How about ATM's Journey Planner?

Just for kicks you can try to run a journey search from Malpensa to Linate using [ATM's very own journey planner](http://giromilano.atm.it/#/home/) (disclaimer: as a tool it's horrifyingly non-intelligent, as you would expect any blunt path optimisation algorithm to be). The tool does suggest walking the 38000-something meters separating Malpensa from Rho, and from there taking two metro lines until Lambrate, leaving you 5050-something meters to walk to reach Linate. You simply can't make this stuff up:

[image: giro milano insanity]

In hindsight this might be perfect to kill off that long 9-10 hour layover you mentioned.

Comment: the ATM journey planner is meant to be used for the urban lines. 

Use the trenord or trenitalia journey planners if you want to inform yourself about a train ride. 
In my country there is more integration so the train thing also plans for local public transport but I don't think there's any website that does that in Italy.

Comment: @Formagella It does suggest other more sensible alternatives, including the Malpensa Express and Shuttle. However I found it hilarious that it suggests walking 38km into Milano and 5.5km out of Milano. The latter is even more hilarious since the 73 is *the* public transport serving Linate and hence suggesting it should be a no brainer. Moreover, as to your observation, that part of the journey is incidentally an urban one.