# How to use Uber my account with a different country sim but same email address

Tags: uber

I have a different country sim to my country of origin account. When I put in the new number, I receive the OTP  so that works fine, but it will not let me get past the email address. It says it is already registered. The email address is the same as my country of origin account.

I want to book an Uber in NZ but can’t get beyond the prompt that says my email account is already registered.. please advise.

Comment: I don't believe you can -- I permanently lost access to a previous acct this way, and it took weeks of back & forth with support to be able to use the same card again on a new acct for payments -- but I'd love to be proved wrong.

Comment: Oh dear, thank you for sharing this...I thought they were supposed to be available world wide. Surely we don’t have register in each country with a new email address! As a world traveller that seems very silly.

Answer (score 2):

The steps are as following:

1. Login to your Uber account with the old SIM card
2. Change your SIM card
3. Open the Uber app and [change your number](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/74855/is-there-a-practical-way-to-change-the-phone-number-in-uber-app-when-arriving-at). Optionally you can also change your name to something that's easy to pronounce for locals.

Alternatively you can just register a new Uber account by [adding a dot](https://www.lifewire.com/easy-gmail-address-hacks-1616186) in your email address - e.g. if your address is xyz@gmail.com, you can use x.yz@gmail.com instead. As a rider there's pretty much no benefits to having an old account, unless you have a lot of free rides stored up from sharing your promo link.

Comment: Just to add that adding a . into an email is fine with Gmail but doesn't work for all email providers, definitely try sending a normal email to that address to check it can be received before using it in Uber.

Comment: [Sub-addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Subaddressing)  is supported by many mail operators but often rather  than a `.` dot other mail servers might use the `+` plus or a `-` hyphen as the separator.